Zero W 2 with headphone jack and volume control
New to raspberry pi's and I was wondering how to play a .mp3 file from the pi to a headphone jack and be able to control the volume levels. I was searching around but I was very confused because I saw a bunch of different circuits for the jack that look complicated and with no hardware links for it. Also all of these look like they have a set volume level and I would like to be able to vary that. Basically, I am very confused on the whole topic and would like some guidance and advice for what/how to get started with this task.

a bunch of different circuits for the jack - which jack? there is no jack

A Raspberry Pi normally runs an entire Operating System (OS) with many different possible ways to accomplish your project. Your question is akin to arriving in a new city on a bus and asking a passerby what type of gas to buy. Since there's no head phone jack on a Raspberry Pi zero (W) I would buy a USB to head phone jack and use one of the many possible Linux media players to decode MP3 compression format and control the volume. Respond if this is the answer you want and I'll add links to parts and instructions.
